# Find users who have min and max rating?

Tags: mysql

I have a `Ratings(User_ID, Rating)` [table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EL8au.png), The minimum rating for user is `1` and the maximum rating is `12`

**My question is**: How to get users, who have both ratings, `1` and `12` ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please check these links to learn [How to write effective questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) or [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I correctly understand, you need this:

```
select user_id from t where 
rating IN(1,12)
group by user_id
having count(distinct rating) = 2
```

If there no chance that same rating may repeated for same user, then you can use `count(rating)` instead.